# Cumulative sum of a column in Julia DataFrame

Tags: julia

In Python Pandas if I want to create a new column with the cumulative sum of an existing column I do:

```
df['cumulative_sum'] = df.scores.cumsum()
```

What would be the equivalent way of doing this in Julia?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Base method `cumsum` to calculate the cumulative sum of a vector, and then store that in a new column of the dataframe:

```
df[!, :cumulative_sum] = cumsum(df[!, :scores]) # the ! is to avoid copying
```

Per @Bogumił Kamiński's comment below, you can also do:

```
df.cumulative_sum = cumsum(df.scores)
```

which is cleaner syntax.

Comment: or `df.cumulative_sum = cumsum(df.scores)`.

Comment: Please consider adding @Bogumil Kaminski's comment to your answer to make it more visible.